# Python looping through nested arrays

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, iteration

I have a json that looks like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "status":"passed",
      "elements":[{"name":"foo"},{"name":"bar"}]
   },
   {  
      "status":"failed",
      "elements":[{"name":"foo1"},{"name":"bar1"}]
   }
]
```

I am trying to iterate through the elements array:

```
for a in json['elements']:
   print a['name']
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

My python is really bad. Thank you

Comment: `json['elements']` gives you a list of two items: `{"name":"foo1"}, and {"name":"bar1"}`, so you need to index into it with an integer, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for a in json:
   for b in a['elements']:
       print b['name']
```

Comment: BTW, your data structure is not a JSON, it's an array of JSONs.

Answer (score 0):

With your code, you are trying to get the value of the key `'elements'` from the dictionary `json`. But `json` isn't a dict, but an array of dicts. Thus, what you should do instead is:

```
for dic_x in json:
    for dic_y in dic_x['elements']:
        print dic_y['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your `list` and then proceed with your data like what you do with `dicts` like this example:

```
my_json = [  
   {  
      "status":"passed",
      "elements":[{"name":"foo"},{"name":"bar"}]
   },
   {  
      "status":"failed",
      "elements":[{"name":"foo1"},{"name":"bar1"}]
   }
]

for element in my_json:
    for v in element["elements"]:
        print(v["name"])
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
foo1
bar1
```